# One can't possibly visit a network, right? (aka change "Visit Stack Exchange" wording)

Tags: feature-request, top-bar, wording

The left part of the top bar now open a nice drop down when clicked:

> [image]

That's nice and dandy, however Stack Exchange is a **network** of sites, as the banner title itself says. It's not really possible to "visit" a network, but rather the network portal, or similar word.

I suggest changing the button text to something like "Visit Stack Exchange Portal", or even better let the user know what's expecting them, which is "View Hot Network Questions", which is the default page on https://stackexchange.com/.

Comment: What your asking is actually as simple as adding an extra word like "Portal" or "Dashboard"...

Comment: @iDebug indeed.

Answer (score 0):

<s>On Facebook, you'll be prompted "*Be the first to object*"</s>

I don't really think this is an issue.

From my knowledge, what you're asking is essentially adding an extra word such as "Portal" or "Dashboard" to differentiate the SE front page from the term "Stack Exchange Network". This is mostly useless.

Let's grab another example, Google. You surely doesn't mean the whole Google product family when you say "Visit Google". You're probably referring to it's flagship service, online searching. This is the same for SE. "Visit Stack Exchange" mostly means "visit the SE front page". So it's unnecessary to add an extra word.

Comment: "This is the same for SE" - no, not really. The flagship of SE and the place everyone knows is Stack Overflow. Only few know about the stackexchange.com site, and most people will just be baffled when landing there anyway. I suggest making it a bit less surprise. :)

Comment: "Meta Whatever" - "Meta" = "Whatever" (name for the main site)